# URL to promote your app on facebook/twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter

I am thinking about adding facebook/twitter buttons in the apps I'm creating, but one thing has been puzzling me. The URLs of my apps are of course Google play URLs, like this:

market://details?id=com.mycompany.mygame

but if I promote this URL in a facebook message or tweet then the receiver of the message will only be able to click on the URL if they happen to be looking at it on an Android device, if they're not, they will get an error report from their browser. I could instead point to the market web URL like this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.mygame

But it feels rather clumsy. So my question is this: - is there a way to tweet or facebook-like an app in a way where the receiver of the message will see the most appropriate URL for their device?

Comment: Is this a development question?

Comment: That's arguable...

Comment: Why is the web URL clumsy? On Android devices, the browser should suggest opening the URL in Play Store and shows the same as the first URL, and on other devices the web page is shown. If it's the length, use a trustworthy URL shortener.

Comment: "On Android devices, the browser should suggest opening the URL in Play Store" - it doesn't happen with my (dolphin) browser. Instead I see the web page - and the "Install" button on the web page is so small I have to zoom in to be able to read it.

Comment: @Mick: That's probably because in the dim-and-distant past, you set the Dolphin browser to be the default when opening suck links. I'll bet if you clear the defaults for Dolphin you'll once again be prompted for how to open a `play.google.com` URL, and one of the options will be the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play.google.com link you post is the correct form for linking to an app, and it's the [documented solution recommended by Google](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails).